ApexCRUDViolation: check for object-level delete permission does not work
I am trying to check for object-level delete permission on a custom object before performing a DML delete operation on it.
The check is performed as it is shown in documentation here.
Here is the simplest version of the class:
public with sharing class TestClassApex {
    public static void exampleMethod() {
        List<CBConfig__c> configs = [SELECT Id FROM CBConfig__c WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
        if (Schema.SObjectType.CBConfig__c.isDeletable()) {
            delete configs;
        }
    }
}

Please, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm already losing it.
I'm running the check through:
sf scanner run --format csv --outfile CodeAnalyzerGeneral.csv --target ./ --category Security

And getting:

P.S.:
Also tried like this and no luck:
if (CBConfig__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isDeletable()) {
    delete configs;
}


Do you have the correct/latest ruleset installed for PMD/the scanner?

I believe that yes, because I ran: sf plugins install @salesforce/sfdx-scanner@latest-beta. Version 4.1.

I also tried with the version 3.23.

I have tagged Robert Soesemann on X to see if he can shed light here.

@PhilW Thank you!

@MariiaIllarionova, I confirm that this is not as expected. The issue is that the PMD rules the scanner is using have become outdated over the years and need to be fixed by Salesforce with a new definitive rule. User Mode, Security Enforced etc. I contacted the guy at Salesforce to look into this.

@RobertSösemann Thank you!

@MariiaIllarionova I talked to DSalesforce and they asked to create a ticket in the Code Analyser repo at https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-scanner/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md.
I also created this ticket on the PMD repo https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/4997 , but the effort to fix this rule needs to be coordinated between PMD and Salesforce. In the meantime, I recommend you Suppress those warnings OR use User Mode solutions.

@RobertSösemann I have raised an issue in the repository you provided https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-scanner/issues/1458

Confirmed as an issue.
Solution that does not include check on isDeletable() (docs):
delete as user configs;
// OR
Database.delete(configs, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);

Linked issues:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-scanner/issues/1458 (raised by me)
https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/4997 (raised by @Robert Sösemann)

I feel like this is a bug, because you're doing all the right things, but perhaps not in the right order that the scanner expects. I'd have to check the rule to be certain. For now, you can probably fix this with:
public with sharing class TestClassApex {
    public static void exampleMethod() {
        if(!sObjectType.CBConfig__c.accessible || !sObjectType.CBConfig__c.deletable) {
          return;
        }
        List<CBConfig__c> configs = [SELECT Id FROM CBConfig__c];
        delete configs;
    }
}

This also saves you a query if the user shouldn't be able to access the object to begin with. Note that WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED isn't needed in this context, because you're already using with sharing and the field you selected, Id, is always visible.
The scanner also might not recognize the newer methods, so you may be stuck with using isAccessible() and isDeletable() if you want to avoid the error. Otherwise, just use // NOPMD to suppress the warnings for now.

Thank you, will try that tomorrow and accept the answer in case!

Unfortunately, that also didn't help. Just worth the mention, but I am using WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED in the class with sharing only because it passes pmd rules. If I remove it and add check on accessible, it shows the issue. I tried deletable in both configurations with delete inside the if-clause and with return inside the not-if-clause, both aren't working. I think I will add @SuppressWarnings('PMD.ApexCRUDViolation') for now. Thank you again!

@MariiaIllarionova You could also instead use a WITH USER_MODE in your SOQL and delete as user configs. That is a recommended new way of doing things and is already accepted by current PMD rules.

Awesome! Thank you very much!

This may help you out. 
public with sharing class TestClassApex { 
    public static void exampleMethod() {
        // Check if the user has delete permission on the CBConfig__c object
        if (Schema.SObjectType.CBConfig__c.isDeletable()) {
            // Query the records only if the user has delete permission
            List<CBConfig__c> configs = [SELECT Id FROM CBConfig__c];
            // Perform the delete operation
            delete configs;
        } 
    }

You can query if you have the delete permission or not.

Nope, that's not the case. I tried it and it didn't work. Also I have WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED in the SOQL query, so that's automatically checks for the isAccessible(). But thank you for the try anyway)
